# Arbitrary linear transformation of a vector of matrices?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

How do I write a transformation of a vector of matrices so that it "hits" the matrix elements with the general linear group?

Say I have

$$
v=\pmatrix{M_1\\\vdots\\M_m},
$$

where $M_1,\dots,M_m$ are $n\times n$ matrices. Note that a transformation in this space is:

$$
T=\pmatrix{M_{00} & \dots & M_{0m} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ M_{m0} & \dots & M_{mm}}
$$

Now, say I want to "hit" every element of v with a general linear transformation  $GMG^{-1}=M'$ using $T$ as the transformation. I assume I need to hammer $v$ from both directions?

The problem is that transformations of $v$ are done from the left side $Tv=v'$, but the elements of $v$ need to be hammered from both sides.

What is the most general transformation that hits $v$ both ways?
$$
(Tv)^TT^{-1}=v'
$$

What if it is complex

$$
(Tv)^HT^{-1}=v'\,?
$$